# Options to get 12 digital inputs

Tags: gpio, sensor

I'm interested in building a monitoring system for my 4-zone HVAC system, which will require monitoring between 8 and 12 separate 24VAC circuits.   Following a suggestion in [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4606/is-arduino-a-good-platform-for-monitoring-24vac-thermostat-circuits), I plan to use MID400 optocouplers to convert the 24VAC signals to digital, but I'm not sure how to get the 12 separate inputs into the PI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look at the [MCP23017 i2c 16 input/output port expander](http://adafruit.com/products/732).

It gives you 16 i/o ports and communicates to the Raspberry Pi via I2C so it only takes 2 pins.

Comment: Looks like a good solution; ordering one (and a batch of MID400s) soon.,